# jinja2 - how to put a block in an if statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, flask, jinja2

I am trying to use an `if` to determine which block should fill my `{% block content %}`.

I have a `base.html` which has a default `{% block content %}` and this template is extending `base.html`. So I tried this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% if condition == True %}
    {% block content %}
    <div>blah blah blah blah</div>
    {% endblock content %}
{% endif %}
```

and I was expecting to see `blah blah blah blah` if condition was true and see the default block if it wasn't true.

But both times I got `blah blah blah blah`.

Then I tried this one:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% if condition == True %}
    {% block content %}
    <div>blah blah blah blah</div>
    {% endblock content %}
{% else %}
    {% block content %}
    <div>The Default Thing</div>
    {% endblock content %}
{% endif %}
```

and I got this error:

```
TemplateAssertionError: block 'content' defined twice
```

How can I put a block inside an `if` statement?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You cannot make a `{% block %}` conditional; once you use the tag, the block is always going to be filled in.

Put your conditional **inside** the block instead, and use `super()` to instruct Jinja to use the original contents of the block as defined in the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if condition %}
        <div>blah blah blah blah</div>
    {% else %}
        {{ super() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```