# If statement not working in Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am working with jija2. I am not sure weather I am missing something, but the mentioned if statement (`{%if actors%}...{%endif%}`) does not seems to be working.

`actors` is a list of movie names.

```
{%if actors%}
  {%block movies%}
     <div class='card-activity col-md-4' id="material-card-info">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
           <thead>
        <tr>
        <th><h5 style="color:#E91E63; font-weight:lighter; font-height:;">Actors</h5></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {%for actor in actors%}
            <tr><td>{{actor}}</td></tr>
        {%endfor%}
        </tbody>
      </table> 
    </div>
  {%endblock%}
{%endif%}
```

Here's the view function:

```
@app.route('/movie/<b64>')
def profile_movie(b64):
    profile = database_search_withid(b64) #returns a tuple eg: ('Avatar', 2012, ['Sam Worthington', 'Zoe Saldana'])
    if not profile:
        abort(404)
    cast= json.loads(profile[2]) #list of actors obtained above is json
    actor, actress = filter_feature(cast) #returns actor and actress in separate list
    print show
    return render_template('movie_profile.html', song_entries=profile, actors=actor, actresses=actress)
```

The `div` inside `{%if actors%}` is showing even when the list is empty. What am i missing?

Comment: And what is the content of actor object before you call the render template?

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel in the above example it would be: `['Sam Worthington', 'Stephen Lang', 'Giovanni Ribisi'] ` etc

Comment: The anwer to the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655031/jinja2-how-to-put-a-block-in-an-if-statement) seems to suggest that blocks cannot be conditional, have you tried putting the `if` inside the `{% block %}`?

Comment: @ca508 Yup that did it. Thanks